# React state not updated inside event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have a state variable that determines whether a button is rendered. The onclick handler of the button toggles the state and is supposed to remove the button. But the state never gets updated inside the event handler (works fine in Safari by the power of God). All other function calls work fine. But the state never gets updated, not even with a delay (checked in devtools). It looks something like..

```
const [shown, setShown] = useState(true)

return (
  shown ? (
    <button
      onClick={(ev) => {
        console.log(shown) // outputs true
        setShown(false) // does absolutely nothing, no errors
        console.log(shown) // outputs true
      }}
    ></button>
  ) : (
    <OtherElement />
  )
)
```

This is a simplified version I guess. I 'solved' this by changing onClick to

```
onClick={ () => 
  setTimeout(
    setShown.bind(undefined, false)
  ,0)
}
```

I'm not sure if this is ideal or not. Any ideas?

Comment: I have asnwered your question below, if it helps please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because React batches the `setState` try having a handler funcion and add a `useEffect` like this

```
useEffect(()=>{ console.log("Shown Chnaged") },[shown])
```

when you are setting state it doesn't immediately re-render because of React's batching mechanism

Refer to [this](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2) article for more

Comment: This is even weirder now. If I add the useEffect, the effect runs when the button is clicked. But the state still isn't updated (in devtools) and the UI isn't either. If I console.log(shown) inside the effect, it outputs alternating values of true/false even though the handler constantly only sets the state to false.

Comment: I made a sample app, refer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jaucsz?file=src/App.js), it works as expected, there value is not alternating

Comment: There's probably something else in the code that's affecting this. I'm gonna mark it as answered since this solves the code I've posted. Thanks for the example and everything.